# In Fortran, what is the difference between passing myArray or myArray(:) to a function?

Tags: arrays, fortran, mpi, subset

As the title says, I'm interested in what the type difference is between an array itself and a subset of the array.  For background, I'm passing the array into an MPI function which triggers an 'array index out of bounds' error when called with a zero length array, but only with the subset notation.  Here is a simplified example of the issue at hand:

```
real(4), allocatable :: myData(:)

allocate(myData(numElements), STAT=iStat)

! The following calls only differ in the second argument
! Passing array itself always works (e.g. myData)
call MPI_FILE_WRITE_ALL(file, myData, MPI_REAL4, numElements, &
                        MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, mpiErr)

! Passing converted subset always works (e.g. real(myData(:), 4)
call MPI_FILE_WRITE_ALL(file, real(myData(:), 4), MPI_REAL4, numElements, &
                        MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, mpiErr)

! Passing subset works unless numElements is zero
call MPI_FILE_WRITE_ALL(file, myData(:), MPI_REAL4, numElements, &
                        MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, mpiErr)
```

Here is a link to the [documentation for MPI_FILE_WRITE_ALL](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/current/man3/MPI_File_write_all.3.php), but it appears to just need BUFFER(*).  Any thoughts as to why these different calls behave so differently?

Comment: One discussion of the differences at http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/03/31/doctor-it-hurts-when-i-do-this/

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question on your title:

When passing an array-slice a temporary array must be created and the data must be copied into it, when passing the whole array this is not required and a reference to the original array is used instead of making a copy.

As is mentioned in the link provided by M. S. B. and in the comments, passing the slice also causes a loss of the array bounds information.

Comment: This doesn't address the points in the body of the question, merely the very non-specific title.  However, in this latter it is overly simplistic.  Copy-in isn't a "must" for an array slice, and isn't a "must not" for a whole-array: even for a whole-array if the dummy argument has the `value` attribute there must be copying.  Regarding "loss of bounds", this applies only to deferred-shape arrays which is unlikely to be the case in this question.  For assumed-shape arrays bounds information is not passed whatever the form of the actual argument.

Comment: @francescalus Fair enough, out of interest how do you avoid a copy when passing a slice?

Comment: One would generally hope for a compiler avoiding copying whenever possible, but these things will vary by compiler/compile options.  Note that many compilers offer diagnostics for when copying occurs.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Making a temporary copy is not indicated in standard and thus depends on compiler. I have tested sending slices of relatively big arrays in ifort compiler and I believe no temporary copy is made by compiler because the timing was exactly equal to passing the reference. However when I intentionally copy-send then the timing is significantly slow. When a slice is send, the compiler manage to basically send the Dope Vector http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dope_vector NOT NECESSARILY making a copy of the slice.